# Propagating through a custom layer in tensorflow just once

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, layer

Given a custom layer in tensorflow, is it possible to let the model use it just during one epoch? The layer may just be ignored for all other epochs or simple be an identity.

For example: Given data I would like the layer to simply double the given data. The other layers should may work normally. How would one do that?

```
def do_stuff(data):
      return 2*data

def run_once(data):
  return tf.py_func(do_stuff, 
                     [data],
                     'float32',
                     stateful=False,
                     name='I run once')


class CustomLayer(Layer):
  def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
    self.output_dim = output_dim
    self.trainable = False
    super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def call(self, x):
    res = tf.map_fn(run_once, x)
    res.set_shape([x.shape[0],
                   self.output_dim[1], 
                   self.output_dim[0],
                   x.shape[-1]])
    return res

inputs = Input(shape=(224, 224, 1))    
x = Lambda(preprocess_input(x), input_shape=(224, 224, 1), output_shape=(224, 224, 3))
outputs = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model(input=inputs, output=outputs)
output = model(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. To execute a TF operation just in the first epoch, one could use [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) and [tf.control_dependencies](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) to check/update the value of a boolean tensor. For example, your custom layer could be implemented as follows:

```
class CustomLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.first_epoch = tf.Variable(True)

    def call(self, x):
        res = tf.cond(self.first_epoch,
                      true_fn=lambda: run_once(x),
                      false_fn=lambda: x)
        with tf.control_dependencies([res]):
            assign_op = self.first_epoch.assign(False)
            with tf.control_dependencies([assign_op]):
                res = tf.identity(res)
        return res
```

To validate that this layer works as expected, define `run_once` as:

```
def run_once(data):
    print_op = tf.print('First epoch')
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
        out = tf.identity(data)
    return out
```

Comment: This looks interesting! One doubt though: What happens, if one uses layer this during prediction? For training, it is simple to let every batch run through your the "run once" path. The layer may just count the number of data or batches received thus far and stops after a fixed number of steps. (One does know that beforehand.) 
Saving the model, letting someone else use it for prediction might be then a different story though :/

Comment: If one uses this layer during prediction, the behavior will depend on the state of `first_epoch` (first_batch might be a better name, actually). If the network has been trained, the state will be `False` and `run_once` won't be executed at prediction time. And vice-versa. I am not sure what is the expected behavior at prediction time, but it could be easily modified by incorporating the [learning phase](https://keras.io/backend/#learning_phase) into the logics. As for saving the model, there shouldn't be any problem because the flag `first_epoch` is a variable that can be restored.